# Windows ec2 machine not loading user scripts

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

When I deploy ec2 machine the user scipts are not loading. For example it is not mounting and copying the file. When I check the userData script's it is showing the folowing logs.

This is my user data

```
<script>
mount \\fssome_value.amazonaws.com\fsx\ F:
xcopy /y F:\Name C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Name /e
</script>
```

This is the UserdataExecution.log log

```
022/06/15 06:40:03Z: Userdata execution done
2022/06/28 06:54:04Z: Userdata execution begins
2022/06/28 06:54:04Z: Zero or more than one <persist> tag was not provided
2022/06/28 06:54:04Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2022/06/28 06:54:04Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
2022/06/28 06:54:08Z: Zero or more than one <runAsLocalSystem> tag was not provided
2022/06/28 06:54:08Z: Zero or more than one <script> tag was not provided
2022/06/28 06:54:08Z: Zero or more than one <powershellArguments> tag was not provided
2022/06/28 06:54:08Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2022/06/28 07:05:31Z: Userdata execution begins
2022/06/28 07:05:32Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty
2022/06/28 07:05:37Z: Userdata was not provided
2022/06/28 07:05:37Z: Userdata execution done
```

Tried even with startup script but it is not executing unless I log in to the server .

I want to either load this in user script while starting the server or need to execute the script from startup while deploying the server without logging into the machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the userdata isn't formatted properly? There's a typo in what should be the opening `<script>`

Comment: @paolo made a mistake while copying . Corrected it now . Thanks

Comment: Is it a custom AMI? What is the version of windows server? In the logs, you can see ``Failed to get metadata ``. Check the route table (``route print``). Can you get simple information? ``(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)``

Comment: @FranxiHidro Yes it is a custom AMI. The interesting thing is , using userdata it is not even executing this command .

<script>
echo Current date and time >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
echo %DATE% %TIME% >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
</script>
<persist>true</persist>

Comment: Can you provide the output of my comment?

Comment: How are you deploying this instance?